# EF code generation: How to get a System enum to work as an EdmEnumType?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, code-generation

I'm experimenting with writing my own code generation template to mimic the Legacy ObjectContext template that comes with Visual Studio.  Have jumped through several hoops already; now I'm at one that I can no longer reconcile with my previous code.

I have a table where one of the fields represents a `System.DayOfWeek`.  But since I've taken the "DB first" approach, I couldn't define the field as that type; rather, I had to define my own enum type and link it to the `System.DayOfWeek` thusly:

[image]

Now I set the type of my field like so:

[image]

This worked fine under the legacy ObjectContext template, because it generated this:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek
{
    get
    {
        return _DayOfWeek;
    }
    set
    {
        OnDayOfWeekChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("DayOfWeek");
        _DayOfWeek = (DayOfWeek)StructuralObject.SetValidValue((int)value, "DayOfWeek");
        ReportPropertyChanged("DayOfWeek");
        OnDayOfWeekChanged();
    }
}
private DayOfWeek _DayOfWeek;
partial void OnDayOfWeekChanging(DayOfWeek value);
partial void OnDayOfWeekChanged();
```

but the downside was that all over my code I had to do explicit conversions between `System.DayOfWeek` and `SchoolManagement.BL.DayOfWeek`.

Now I'm all excited because my new code template generates this directly as a `System.DayOfWeek`, so I don't need to do any more explicit conversions:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public System.DayOfWeek DayOfWeek
{
    get
    {
        return _dayOfWeek;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_dayOfWeek != value)
        {
            OnDayOfWeekChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("DayOfWeek");
            _dayOfWeek = (System.DayOfWeek)StructuralObject.SetValidValue((System.Int32)value, "DayOfWeek");
            ReportPropertyChanged("DayOfWeek");
            OnDayOfWeekChanged();
        }
    }
}
private System.DayOfWeek _dayOfWeek;
```

But for some reason at runtime, as soon as I create my data context, I get a `MetadataException`:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> The property 'DayOfWeek' on type 'SchoolManagement.BL.A2_SchoolHours' is attributed with EdmScalarPropertyAttribute but returns the type 'System.DayOfWeek', which is not a primitive type or a recognized enumeration type.

Uh... whut?  `System.DayOfWeek` is not a recognized enumeration type?  So let's compare to another custom enum, just a few lines earlier in the code, which does not cause any complaints about the metadata:

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public Grade Grade
{
    get
    {
        return _grade;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_grade != value)
        {
            OnGradeChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("Grade");
            _grade = (Grade)StructuralObject.SetValidValue((System.Byte)value, "Grade");
            ReportPropertyChanged("Grade");
            OnGradeChanged();
        }
    }
}
private Grade _grade;
```

In the definition of the `Grade` enum, there's a decorator:

```
[EdmEnumType(NamespaceName = "SchoolManagement.BL", Name = "Grade")]
[DataContract]
public enum Grade : byte
{
```

I'm guessing that the `EdmEnumType` there is what makes it work.  So how do I get that to apply to `System.DayOfWeek`?

Comment: If you were to make a small code-first project containing a class with a `DayOfWeek` property, perhaps that will show you how your code should be structured...

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, code first doesn't require all these decorators that are messing me up.  But the DB First code generation tool does generate them, and I can't live without them.

Comment: @ShaulBehr Why don't you try using 'DbContext' instead of 'ObjectContext'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered a limitation of Entity Framework: http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback/details/739409/adding-enum.

Your approach will work if you change a code generation template: use DbContext instead of ObjectContext.

If you want to stay with ObjectContext, you should implement the following changes:

1) move the definition of your enum to the assembly with your descendant of ObjectContext

2) put the EdmEnumType attribute (and set the values of Name and NamespaceName)

3) specify the DataContract and EnumMember attributes if you need 
serialization/deserialization

```
namespace Model {
  [System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmEnumTypeAttribute(Name = "Enum1", NamespaceName = "Model")]
  [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract()]
  public enum Enum1 {
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
    a,
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMember()]
    b
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're defining an EF enumeration based of an existing one, you shouldn't need to define the enumeration values.

Try removing those from the "Edit Enum Type" dialog.

Comment: Well, yes, that is true, but it's irrelevant to the question.  How should I generate this property so that EF doesn't complain about an invalid schema?